# Create config file at runtime in Java exported WAR

Tags: java, eclipse, file, tomcat, war

I've made a web project with eclipse to run my webservice on Tomcat v7. I have a config file that have to define some variables that should be changed while webserver is up without need of restart it. The problem is: where I can put this file?
At the moment I've put it into the "./" dir, but seems that when I export the WAR file and install it on the webserver it doesn't works. Is there a way to create this file and modify it runtime inside the WAR?

Here is part of the code of the .class file that accesses the config file

```
public class ToolConfigurations {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ToolConfigurations.class);   //Oggetto logging

    private static ToolConfigurations instance = null;  //verificarne la necessità

    private static String defaultServerName = null;
    private static String defaultDbName = "postgres";
    private static String defaultDbUser = "postgres";
    private static String defaultDbPass = "password";
    private static int defaultDbMaxConnNum = 10;

    private static String configFilePath = ".\\";
    private static String configFileName = "tool.properties";
    private String serverName = null;
    private String dbName = null;
    private String dbUser = null;
    private String d`enter code here`bPass = null;
    private int dbMaxConnNum = -1;

    private ToolConfigurations() throws Exception {
        File file = new File(configFilePath + configFileName);
        if(file.exists()) {
            //file configurazione esiste
            FileReader in = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //Leggo riga per riga il file 
                String[] values = line.split(" ");
                switch (values[0]) {
                    case "serverName":
                        serverName = values[1];
                        break;
                    case "dbName":
                        dbName = values[1];
                        break;
                    case "dbUser":
                        dbUser = values[1];
                        break;
                    case "dbPass":
                        dbPass = values[1];
                        break;
                    case "dbMaxConnNum":
                        dbMaxConnNum = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        log.warn("Elemento inaspettato nel file di configurazione: " + values[0]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            br.close();
            in.close();
        }else {
            if(file.createNewFile() == false) {
                //Errore creazione file
                log.error("Errore creazione file di configurazione");
                throw new Exception("Errore creazione file configurazione");
            }
            //CREO FILE CONFIGURAZIONE CON IMPOSTAZIONI DI DEFAULT
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write("dbName " + defaultDbName + "\r\n");
            fw.write("dbUser " + defaultDbUser + "\r\n");
            fw.write("dbPass " + defaultDbPass + "\r\n");
            fw.write("dbMaxConnNum " + defaultDbMaxConnNum + "\r\n");
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
            log.warn("File di configurazione non trovato. Path: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + ". Creato nuovo file con configurazioni di default.");
            //CARICO IMPOSTAZIONI DI DEFAULT
            dbName = defaultDbName;
            dbUser = defaultDbUser;
            dbPass = defaultDbPass;
            dbMaxConnNum = defaultDbMaxConnNum;
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ToolConfigurations getInstance() throws Exception {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ToolConfigurations();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: WAR's are not intended to be modified at runtime.  That said, you can manipulate an exploded (unzipped) war.  I would recommend against it.  You might find putting your configuration in JNDI a better idea.

Comment: I need a place where to put and reach my config files indipendently from the ambient I put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to a ClassLoader to search for the config file that I have previously created into the main directory.
The example of use is:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream fileInput = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(configFileName);
if(fileInput == null){
    //File not found
}else{
    //File found
    InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr);
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            //Read file line by line
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Error parsing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In web server, files other than .class are directly taken in charge by the server. You don't need to reload the server.

But try using **.properties** files and check the structure of the WAR when deployed on the server.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a .properties file, but the problem is: how to link relatively to it?

Comment: Please post a part of your code specially how you do to access your file.